# C# socket program multithreading and data exchange

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying get the server to receive a student ID from any client, it looks up the XML file to search and return the student's major like 'PHYSICS'.

Once a client receives the major of the student, and it sends the major immediately back to the server without user input. When the server receives a major and not a student ID, it looks up again the same XML file to find the major's average GPA and return it to the client.

The server accepts one or two clients connection but no more than two at any time.

server_g.exe.confg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key = "U101" value="PHYSICS"/>
    <add key = "U102" value="EDU"/>
    <add key = "U103" value="EDU"/>
    <add key = "PHYSICS" value="3.11"/>
    <add key = "EDU" value="2.96"/>
    <add key = "U104" value="EE"/>
    <add key = "U105" value="PHYSICS"/>
    <add key = "EE" value="3.02"/>  
    <add key = "U106" value="EE"/>
    <add key = "U107" value="EDU"/>
    <add key = "U108" value="EE"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ClientSocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 2055);
            try
            {
                Stream s = client.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter students information: ");
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(title);
                    if (title == "") 
                        break;
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
                s.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

server code:

//SERVER SIDE PROGRAM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ServerSocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static TcpListener listener;
        const int LIMIT = 2; 
        public static void Query()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected: {0}", soc.RemoteEndPoint);
                try
                {    
                    Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc);
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                    sw.AutoFlush = true; // enable automatic flushing
                    sw.WriteLine("{0} books available", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count);
                    string title = Console.ReadLine();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string bookTitle = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (bookTitle == "" || bookTitle == null) 
                            break;
                        string price = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[bookTitle];
                        if (price == null) 
                            price = "Sorry, no such book!";
                        sw.WriteLine(price);
                    }
                    s.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected: {0}", soc.RemoteEndPoint);
                soc.Close();
            }
        }
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 
            listener = new TcpListener(ipAd, 2055);
            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server started, listening to port 2055");
            for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Query));
                t.Start();
                //Console.WriteLine("Server thread {0} started....", ++i);
                Console.WriteLine("Server thread {0} started....", i+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use sockets instead of Web Api?

Comment: You are closing the server stream after each message so you are receiving only one message.